# How to customize IgnoreDataMember attribute to handle user roles?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can we customize IgnoreDataMember attribute to handle user roles? I am looking for something like this [IgnoreDataMemeber (Roles = "Admin")].

Also, are there any other attributes to conditionally serialize a property based on the user role?
E.g. [SomeAttribute (Roles = "Admin")].

Comment: Please read this similar question [How to customize IgnoreDataMember attribute to handle user roles?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37169416/how-to-customize-ignoredatamember-attribute-to-handle-user-roles)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do that. Anything that depends on whether a user is in one role or another is application logic. You definitely wouldn't want business logic to be hidden in an attribute with a seemingly unrelated purpose (determining which fields get serialized.) If you could get it to do what you wanted, what would happen if you wanted to save the data using some other serializer or share it some other way? If your logic is built into that attribute then it can't be applied in any other scenario. (Or people will do really weird things with your code because they depend on the serializer to apply business logic.)

To answer your question more directly, no you cannot modify the behavior of this attribute. Its [definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) shows that it is sealed, which means that you can't inherit from it.